# How do you submit a dropdownlist in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, onchange

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm() { %>

  <%=Html.DropDownList("TopItemsList", ViewData["ListData"], new { onchange="[???]" })%>

<% } %>
```

In the above example, what value should you set onchange to? Or, how do you get the correct form?

Is there any difference with Ajax.BeginFrom?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

try this:

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("TopItemsList", ViewData["ListData"], new { onchange="this.form.submit();" })%>
```

Every form element in the has a "form" property that is pointed to the form that contains this element.

Yes, using "Html." and "Ajax." has a difference. Ajax. means that partial page update will be used and the whole page will not be reloaded.

Comment: Just to correct the statement,
<%=Html.DropDownList("TopItemsList", ViewData["ListData"], new { @onchange="this.form.submit();" })%>
note the @ symbol.

Comment: If you have multiple dropdowns or textboxes you need to do this too, I created a CSS class and added this JS.

            $(".ajaxForcePost").change(function () {
                this.form.submit();
            });

Answer (score 6):

Why are you mixing your html with javascript??

Delete the onchange attribute and add some JQuery:

```
$("#TopItemsList").change(function () {

    $("input[type=submit]").click();

});
```

Comment: Will cause issues if you have more than one submit input.