# ASP.NET MVC 2 DropDownList Selected item changed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list on my aspx form and what I want is to refresh the site after I select an item from the list. This is my drop down list:

```
 <%: Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CompanyUserFilterId, new SelectList(Model.CompanyUsers, "Id", "FirstName", Model.CompanyUserFilterId))%>
```

I use it to filter the data shown on the form depending on the selected item on the drop down list. Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need to 'refresh' the site with some sort of client side mechanism onchange. A similar solution using JQuery is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367349/how-do-you-submit-a-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc-from-an-ajax-form).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is probably to trigger an html/javascript onchange-event, and handle that to update your page (or post the form with the selected Id).

Take a look at this: http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/10/21/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlist-and-html-attributes