# chaining the items of Razor DropDownLists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 3 DropDownLists; when I select an item in #1, I want the items in #2 to be filled  according the value of #1.  And when I select an item in #2, the items in #3 should be filled according the selection in #2.  They all are located in a form named `GetItemsForLeve1`.  I've started by using `onchange` of the drop-down.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("GetItemsForLeve1", "Index"))
    { %>             
       Main Group: <%:Html.DropDownList("Level1", (SelectList)ViewBag.Level1, "Select One", new { onchange = "$this.form.submit()" })%> 
       <%:Html.DropDownList("Level2", (SelectList)ViewBag.Level2, "-", new { onchange = "$this.form.submit()" })%> 
       <%:Html.DropDownList("Level3", (SelectList)ViewBag.Level3, "-", new { onchange = "$this.form.submit()" })%> 
         <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    <%}%>
```

1. Is it possible to fill the level 2 and level 3 drop-down lists without sending the page back to the server?
2. How can I tell which drop-down list has been clicked in the `GetItemsForLevel` action?
   I am completely new to MVC, so I appreciate telling me in a simple way?

Thank you

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/4326151/713149

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's not really a component that does this for you.  But you can use the `Ajax.BeginForm` helper to build it.

1. the first ajax form should contain the first select list, and post back to an action that returns a partial view
2. the partial view in 1. should return the second ajax form with a second select list
3. and so forth

So the **main Razor view** should contain something like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SecondAjaxForm", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "secondFormDiv" })
{
    @Html.DropDownList("selectList1", Model.FirstSelectList, new { onchange = "this.form.submit()")
}

<!-- the second AJAX form + drop-down list will get populated here
<div id="secondFormDiv"></div>
```

And the **`SecondAjaxForm` action**:

```
public ActionResult SecondAjaxForm(string selectList1)
{
    SelectList secondSelectList;
    // populate the second select list here
    return PartialView("SecondAjaxForm", secondSelectList);
}
```

The **partial view `SecondAjaxForm`** should be basically the same as the first form above.

```
@model SelectList
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ThirdAjaxForm", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "thirdFormDiv" })
{
    @Html.DropDownList("selectList2", Model, new { onchange = "this.form.submit()")
}

<!-- the third AJAX form + drop-down list (if any) will get populated here
<div id="thirdFormDiv"></div>
```