# Submit form on change of dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms, razor

I'm using MVC 3 and razor and have a form in which there is a dropdown.  How do I submit the form when the value in the dropdown changes?  I have no submit button.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
...

<div class="row">
                    <label>
                        Type of Card</label>
                    <div class="item">
                        @Html.DropDownList("PaymentFormModel.CardType", cardTypes, new { required = "required" })
                    </div>
                </div>
...
}
```

Comment: Can you post your view code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you submit a dropdownlist in asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364505/how-do-you-submit-a-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try like this

```
@Html.DropDownList("PaymentFormModel.CardType", cardTypes, new { required = "required", @onchange="submitform();" })
```

Here is the script for it:

```
function submitform()
{
  $('form').submit();
}
```

hope it helps